# how to encrypt and decrpyt files with adobe air ? (encrypt ok, but decrpyt isn't yet )

Tags: air, encryption

i want to encrypt and decrpyt files with adobe air. and i am successfully encrypt files with code. but i dont yet decrpyt an encrypted file please help me, what can i do?

i am using this code for encrypt:

```
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.AESKey;
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.DESKey;
import com.hurlant.util.Hex;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import com.hurlant.util.ArrayUtil;

stop();

var stream:FileStream;
var stream2:FileStream;
var file:File;

var fileToEncrypt:ByteArray;

encrypt();

function encrypt():void
{
    file = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("logo_markatalog.png");

    fileToEncrypt = new ByteArray;

stream = new FileStream();
stream.open( file, FileMode.READ );
stream.readBytes(fileToEncrypt);
stream.close();

var appDir:String = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath;
//file = File(appDir+"logo_markatalog_enc.png");

file = new File(appDir+"/logo_markatalog_enc.png");

var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("635232557");
var aes:AESKey = new AESKey(key);

aes.encrypt(fileToEncrypt);

stream2 = new FileStream();
stream2.open( file, FileMode.WRITE );
stream2.writeBytes(fileToEncrypt);
stream2.close();
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not currently working? You don't know how to try or you are getting an error? If you are getting an error please post the stacktrace so that there is something to work from.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what you're doing wrong but I can give you what I use to encrypt object into file and decrypt them back.

*someKey* var is your key used to encrypt and decrypt.

*theFileWithEncryptedObject* var is the file where I save my encrypted object in the first code part, from which I read the encrypted object in second code part.

I use an md5 hash on the key, that's not necessary.

Here's the way I encrypt object into file with hurlant.crypto :

```
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(theFileWithEncryptedObject, FileMode.WRITE);
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeObject(theObjectToEncrypt);

var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(someKey);
var md5:MD5 = new MD5();
key = md5.hash(key);

var pad:IPad = new PKCS5();
var aes:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("simple-aes-128-cbc", key, pad);
pad.setBlockSize(aes.getBlockSize());
aes.encrypt(bytes);

fileStream.writeBytes(bytes);
fileStream.close();
```

And here how I decrypt and get back my object from the file :

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(theFileWithEncryptedObject, FileMode.READ);
fileStream.readBytes(bytes);
fileStream.close();

var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(someKey);
var md5:MD5 = new MD5();
key = md5.hash(key);

var pad:IPad = new PKCS5;
var aes:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("simple-aes-128-cbc", key, pad);
pad.setBlockSize(aes.getBlockSize());
aes.decrypt(bytes);

var theObjectDecrypted:Object;
bytes.position = 0;
theObjectDecrypted = bytes.readObject();
```

Hope this helps.